# Ubuntu/Windows dual boot issue

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I first had Windows 8.1 already installed on my machine, and then I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well.

I first shrunk the size of my Windows Disk. Then I installed Ubuntu, splitting it into two partitions (One for swap and the other for the Ubuntu file system).

However, now whenever I attempt to boot via `Windows Boot Manager(on /dev/sda2)`, I get the following error message:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,1f4800,82000,0f6afd19c5af524e,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image.
```

How would I fix it so that Windows 8.1 can boot again as well?

Comment: Why not use Grub as your boot loader instead of Windows Boot Loader?

Comment: I just did the same, but it worked perfectly.
Did you move the start of the windows partition or removed or formated any of the other partitions during the ubuntu installation? If you have a windows DVD, you could let the windows dvd repair the efi boot sector.
After that you can use the ubuntu live cd to install grub again.
This way it should work because youre not moving your partitions.

Comment: Nope didn't remove any partitions and i don't think i have a windows dvd D:

Comment: I found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184137 maybe it helps. You should find out which system boot is installed where and veryfy if it is complete. An then update your question.

Comment: I don't know what grub is sorry

Comment: see this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377979/windows-8-uefi-does-not-boot, worked for me > This looks like bug #1091464. Turn off secure boot in the bios system under the section boot, and you should be able to boot Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Ubuntu on virtual box or VM workstation. or you can turn your physical windows machine into a virtual one using VM workstation and can smoothly dual boot. One other thing that you can do (but i think it's too advanced is to try booting using V Sphere and then work on multiple OSs). I hope this info helps.

Comment: But i've already installed Ubuntu for dual boot and now i cant get into windows and it comes up with this when i try i boot onto windows /EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,1f4800,82000,0f6afd19c5af524e,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image.