# unable to install ubuntu on window as a single O.S. but not working

Tags: boot

i was trying to install ubuntu 14 and 15 on my pre-installed window 10 laptop but my system only shows the ubuntu page that is loading the file. my system configuration is intel i7 1tb 16gb ram and 4gb graphic card please give a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should upgrade your grub so you should follow this instruction :

[unable to boot to windows, boot-repair fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518615/unable-to-boot-to-windows-boot-repair-fails)
if  your problem still remains, do previous step , go to windows and install neo grub from windows and make new grub from windows.
you can get it from :

https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/