# Install GRUB (2x win + linux) on two drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I currently have one HDD (sda) with Windows installed by manufacturer at one partition and Linux installed at another partition. Then, I have SSD (sdb) with second Windows.

What I want to do is to be able to choose in GRUB to boot into Windows on sdb1, Windows on sda4 or Linux on sda6. But when I open grub-customizer, it doesn't show two Windows, but one Windows Boot Manager on sda2.
The first problem is, that since I installed Linux (it installed also GRUB), the Windows Boot Manager doesn't work.

But mainly I don't want to make the Windows Boot Manager work, I'd like to be able to choose both Windows from GRUB (instead of choosing WBM in  GRUB and then again choosing Windows in WBM).

How to make Windows directly bootable from GRUB?
Thanks.

drive info:

sda http://s12.postimg.org/fy07abcnx/Screenshot_from_2016_02_28_18_35_19.png

sdb http://s15.postimg.org/713x6oz6z/Screenshot_from_2016_02_28_18_39_53.png

//edit:
When I choose WBM in GRUB, it writes "cannot load image" and soemthing I don't understand ( s10. postimg. org/d0ij66zm1/20160228_185219.jpg ), but when I enter the BIOS and open BOOT devices, there are, next to drives, options GRUB and Windows Boot Manager. When I launch it from there, it work.

Comment: There is no boot flag on sdb. When you say you can boot into Windows Boot Manager from BIOS, do you mean the Windows on sdb? Run `sudo update-grub` in your terminal, if you haven't. It should find your OSes - on both disks - but if it doesn't something else is wrong.

Comment: @theodorn When I run update-grub, it finds only Windows Boot Manager, but now it's working and I'm able to enter WBM from GRUB and run both Windows (same when entering from BIOS). 
But I'd still like to have both Windows accessible from GRUB. Maybe connect just one drive, reinstall WBM, then connect just second drive and reinstall WBM (so WBM on both disks, each will think there are only one Windows and booting directly into them) and then install GRUB ovr it?

Comment: OK, Linux(sda), Windows(sda) and Windows(sdb) are all accessible from BIOS/UEFI? But only Linux(sda) and Windows(sda) are accessible from GRUB? Do I have it right? Could you post a cellphone picture of the GRUB menu at startup?

Comment: Take a look at this question and the answers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/280339/windows-8-wont-boot-via-grub-after-intalling-12-10-with-boot-repair